# Can a HAVING clause of an SQL query use ONLY aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, having

Our database instructor's lecture slides on `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` make this claim:

[image]

Unfortunately, because the SEO around this topic is so saturated, it's nearly impossible to find a source that answers my question. I can find plenty of examples where `HAVING` is indeed used with aggregates, but does that necessarily imply that it MUST use aggregates?

Based on my understanding and experience, the `HAVING` clause need not *only* use grouping attributes or attributes that appear in aggregates (even though it *can*, unlike its counterpart `WHERE`).

As I understand it, `HAVING` was created because `WHERE` can't operate at the group level.

So, what exactly is stopping me from using any other conditions in a `HAVING` clause, such as a plain old `HAVING attribute = value` condition, where `attribute` appears in neither the `GROUP BY` nor an aggregate in the `SELECT` clause? Visually speaking, it makes perfect sense for me to say:

"Pick only those groups where there's a row that has this value under this column."

Comment: Reading some documentation for `HAVING` may help answer your question. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html notes _Do not use HAVING for items that should be in the WHERE clause. For example, do not write the following:_ `SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name HAVING col_name > 0;` Without an example query I'm a little unclear on what exactly you're asking about, but the documentation should be a good start. Additionally: _The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions._

Comment: Additionally: _The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions._ So it may _work_, though it's not standard, and therefore shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: Although it will work in MySQL that is non-standard SQL and it won't work in standards compliant DBMS such as SQL server, PostgreSQL etc.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57445/use-of-having-without-group-by-in-sql-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HAVING` is like a `WHERE` clause that takes place *after* aggregation. The following two queries are functionally identical (assuming the ellipses are compatible):

```
select key1, key2, . . . 
from t
group by key1, key2
having . . .
```

and:

```
select x.*
from (select key1, key2, . . . 
      from t
      group by key1, key2
     ) x
having . . .
```

The `having` clause can refer to:

- Aggregated values from the `select`.
- keys from the `group by`.
- Functions that take no argument (such as the current date).
- Expressions composed of the above.

It cannot refer to unaggregated columns that are not keys.  Such columns simply do not exist in the result set produced by the `group by`.

There is one exception to this, which I explain at the risk of confusion.  A few databases support columns which are functionally dependent as `group by` keys.  What this means in English is that if the query aggregated by unique/primary keys, then other columns from that table can be used with not aggregation functions.  However, this is an extension to the general rule that the references in the `having` clause are only those available *after* the aggregation.